# How can I make a diagonal division symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

So I want to make the four elementary arithmetic symbols in math-mode, but I don't like the way the divison-symbol looks. I want it to look like you rotated the subtraction-symbol 45 degrees, and I find / looking too long.

[image]

I'd like it to look like the one on the bottom here. One way of doing it was by using \usepackage{graphicx} and inserting `\rotatebox{45}{$\_\!\_\!\_$}`, but this isn't very convenient and I was hoping there may be a better way of making this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this context, you would usually want the division symbol ÷ rather than a slash.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Part of my motivation for using this new sign is to replace it with a symbol looks like a tilted minus-symbol, just as the multiplication-symbol looks like a tilted addition-symbol. Besides, there is no generally accepted division symbol as ) and : could also be used, I just feel it looks better to use a symbol that resembles a fraction, instead of using some weird symbol which doesn't resemble any of the other symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) doesn't give any usable suggestions.

My best result was 
`\newcommand{\division}{\mkern-\medmuskip\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\scalebox{0.9}{$-$}}\mkern-\medmuskip}`

It gives you the same rounded corners as the default division line has.

[image]

edit: notice that this division in my opinion looks horrible for capital variables.

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried Detexify before, but it gave me `$\diagup$`; is there a way to make this symbol shorter? Other than that your solution is certainly better than my current.

Comment: You could use `\scalebox` to shrink it and the fiddle with the spacing, but I couldn't make it prettier than my answer.

Comment: I can't seem to get `\scalebox` to work with `$\diagup$`, \scalebox{0.6}{\diagup} is just erroring. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the error message. You need $'s. `\scalebox{0.6}{$\diagup$}`.

Comment: @corporal the error message was incomprehensible to me. But it seems `\scalebox` made it too thin, so I guess that won't work...

Comment: I used `\rotatebox{45}{\!\scalebox{2}[1]{$\_$}}` instead of your solution, which I think looks fine on both capital and lower case letters.

Answer (score 2):

If the reason for your inconvenience is the lenght or complicatedness of creating that symbol, I kindly remember you of the possibility to define your own command using `\newcommand`, essentially reducing the work needed to create that symbol to a few keystrokes. Also, if you'd decide to use 50 degrees later on, you only have to adjust one piece of code instead of the whole document.

Comment: I'm aware of this option, although I was hoping there was an existing symbol or some better way to write it instead of adding a package for the sake of adding one new symbol. Another reason why I don't like my symbol is that it doesn't have a smooth edge.

Comment: Okay, you should try the answer of @JonasNyrup then, as he seems to have solved the "smooth edge" problem.

Comment: @fvel One of the primary advantages of LaTeX *is* the use of packages (when needed).  A package like `graphicx` needed to accomplish a `\rotatebox` is so useful in so many ways (e.g., `\includegraphics`, `\scalebox`, etc.) that one should not eschew its use.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm aware of the usefulness of packages, but having a package for the sole purpose of adding one new symbol seems unnecessary. Although I was unaware of `graphicx`'s other uses, so perhaps I'll find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

This answer splits the difference between the traditional and proposed approaches.  It introduces `\vfrac{}{}` (vary-frac) which will stretch the top of the fraction to the top of the higher of the two components, but never higher than the top of a capital "X".

For x/y fractions, it gives what the OP seeks, I think.  But if one of the arguments is tall, it stretches the result accordingly.  It is made to work across all math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\vfrac[2]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1#2$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\SavedStyle X$}%
  \ifdim\ht0>\ht2\setlength{\ht0}{\ht2}\fi%
  #1\mathord{\stretchto{\raisebox{2.3\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle/$}}{\ht0}}#2}}
\begin{document}
$\vfrac{x}{y} \quad \vfrac{X}{Y}\quad \vfrac{X^2}{y}\quad \vfrac{p}{q}$\par
$\scriptstyle\vfrac{x}{y} \quad \vfrac{X}{Y}\quad \vfrac{X^2}{y}\quad \vfrac{p}{q}$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\vfrac{x}{y} \quad \vfrac{X}{Y}\quad \vfrac{X^2}{y}\quad \vfrac{p}{q}$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

FOLLOW UP:

The OP asked for a similar approach but with a 45 degree stroke.  Here is such a variation on my approach (though the angle may not be exactly 45 deg).  A downside is that since the slash is scaled (rather than extended), its thickness changes with size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\vfrac[2]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1#2$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\SavedStyle X$}%
  \ifdim\ht0>\ht2\setlength{\ht0}{\ht2}\fi%
  #1\mathord{\scaleto{\raisebox{.7pt}{\vstretch{.3}{\SavedStyle/}}}{\ht0}}#2}}
\begin{document}
$\vfrac{x}{y} \quad \vfrac{X}{Y}\quad \vfrac{X^2}{y}\quad \vfrac{p}{q}$\par
$\scriptstyle\vfrac{x}{y} \quad \vfrac{X}{Y}\quad \vfrac{X^2}{y}\quad \vfrac{p}{q}$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\vfrac{x}{y} \quad \vfrac{X}{Y}\quad \vfrac{X^2}{y}\quad \vfrac{p}{q}$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to always have an angle of 45 degrees, and it seems the angle is changing depending on font size.

Comment: @fvel I have provided a follow up.

Comment: Thanks. I've ended up using `\rotatebox{45}{\!\scalebox{2}[1]{$\_$}}` though, as this doesn't change the thickness and change be of any desired length. Although yours seems more flexible so I might try it as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the Computer Modern fonts, the plus and minus signs have the same lengths of the lines as well as the `\times` symbol, the latter could be considered as rotated plus sign. The division symbol would fit in as rotated minus sign, vertically centered at the math axis and horizontally centered in the width of the `\times` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for environment "gather*"
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\vardivision}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\@vardivision{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@vardivision}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% \ht0: math axis
  \dimen@=\ht0 %
  \sbox0{$#1\times\m@th$}% \wd0: width of the new symbol
  \raise\dimen@\hbox to \wd0{%
    \hfil
    \setbox0=\hbox to \z@{\hss\lower\dimen@\hbox{$#1-\m@th$}\hss}%
    \ht0=\z@
    \dp0=\z@
    \rotatebox{45}{\box0}%
    \hfil
  }%
  \vphantom{\times}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  1 + 2 \times 3 \vardivision 4
\\
  a + b \times c \vardivision d
\\
  {+} {-} {\times} {\vardivision}
\\
  \scriptstyle {+} {-} {\times} {\vardivision}
\\
  \scriptscriptstyle {+} {-} {\times} {\vardivision}
\\
  \sbox0{${+}{-}{\times}{\vardivision}$}
  \rlap{\copy0}%
  \vcenter{%
    \hbox{%
      \textcolor{red}{%
        \vrule width\wd0 height .05pt depth .05pt\relax
      }%
    }%
  }
\\
  \color{red}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
  \def\test#1{\fbox{\textcolor{black}{$#1$}}}
  \vcenter{%
    \hbox{$\test{+} \test{-} \test{\times} \test{\vardivision}$}%
    \nointerlineskip
    \hbox{$\test{-} \test{+} \test{\vardivision} \test{\times}$}%
  }
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can reflect `\smallsetminus` (from `amssymb`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\vardivision}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\@vardivision\relax}% 
}
\newcommand{\@vardivision}[2]{%
  \reflectbox{$\m@th\smallsetminus$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a+b\vardivision c$

$a\vardivision b\times c$

\end{document}
```

[image]